# Which rules are applied If a passenger wants to get off from LHO (live human organ) carrying aircraft, during taxi?

Tags: iata

Which rules are applied If a passenger wants to get off from LHO (live human organ) carrying aircraft, during taxi?

Is the passenger get off from aircraft?
Or Is priority given to LHO?

Is there an international written rule stating which of the priorities?
(ICAO ANNEX, EASA EU OPS, IATA DGR, etc.) Thank you in advance.

Comment: Er, no. You certainly won’t get to leave the aircraft once it has left the gate “because you forgot your keys”.

Comment: If English is not your first language then please say so in your user profile. It will help with interpretation of your question.

Comment: This should be asked in the travel site of Stack Exchange.  Also, the structure of the question needs to be improved.  Remove the hypothetical elements.  Ask it more like, "What laws/regulations exist pertaining to passengers alighting from the aircraft once the gate has been departed?"

Comment: Organs are often transported on their own dedicated flights in smaller aircraft or helicopters for short range operations. Its unlikely there will be both passengers and live human organs at the same time.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is asking where are the rules covering passengers' rights during taxy.  I'm also guessing they are in Annex 2 of the Chicago convention somewhere, but life's too short...

Comment: @Dave Organs can transported commercial flights in special cargo section. It writes IATA DGR book.

Comment: @RyanMortensen I'm trying to move to the travel site. But I can't. Need to create a new topic in travel site?

Comment: @Transistor Thank you for your kindly help. I did.

Comment: @Dave I remember just a few weeks ago a normal passenger flight had to return shortly after takeoff because it forgot to pick up a heart.

Comment: Don't post a new question on the Travel site. If you'd like to have this question moved to that site, please flag this question and the moderators will look at it.

Comment: @NoahKrasser:  That heart was not for transplant; rather the heart valves inside it were to be removed and used for heart valve replacements at a later date (apparently heart valves are not time-sensitive, but full organs are.)  Live organs for immediate transplant are virtually never sent via commercial planes.

Comment: @abelenky does this comment relate to a formal resource? because LHO, which does not require emergency transport, can be sent on commercial flights. See iata dgr book. Also, a passenger who wants to get off the plane can be downloaded for security reasons. see icao annexes and cocpit and cabin crew security guide. Who will decide if they are both? My question is there an official rule of this issue?

Answer (score 8):

Once the doors are closed, the flight is completely under the control and discretion of the Captain.

If she decides not to go back to the gate, the plane does not go back to the gate, no matter what some uppity passenger claims their "rights" are.

Comment: -1 for the tone. As I understand it, certain religions have prohibitions on being around deceased bodies and organs, i.e. Kohen in Judaism. It is not merely an issue of being "uppity".